# A "vector" in the interior differentiation

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I am trying to understand the interior derivative $\cal{i}$$_X \omega$...

$\omega$ is a 1-form; $X$ is a "vector". I have been looking for worked examples here at Math.SE. What confuses me is that, for instance, the "vector" $X$ is defined as, for example

$$X=a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$.

But this is not a vector, it is the differential operator $\vec{A}\cdot\nabla$ (where say, $\vec{A}$=(a,b,0)). This operator can act on both scalars and vectors.

Where did the vector $\vec{X}$ go?
What is the meaning of $X$ in the interior derivative  $\cal{i}$$_X \omega$ ?

Can this derivative work with a 3-vector $\vec{F}=(F_x,F_y,F_z)$?

Comment: Tangent vectors are by (one of the) definition a derivation. In particular, it is defined by it's action on smooth functions. See the definition in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_vector#Tangent_vector_on_manifolds)

Comment: Differential operators are vectors. A vector space is defined very broadly as some set having addition and scalar multiplication by elements of a field. The differential operators on some space of functions form a vector space.

Comment: Matt Samuel, then $X$ is a vector in the broad sense used in linear algebra, but cannot be a $\vec{X}$, or a 3-vector. I am asking, because in examples they show the vector $X$ to appear in expressions as $X^a$, that is, as an entity that has components